# Lost all permissions from directories in Windows 10 and I can't delete them and even take ownership as admin

Tags: windows-10, permissions, ntfs

I was trying to uninstall Rapport a Trusteer application from my computer and the uninstallation program left tracks. So I went to the application's folder and checked that it had System user as owner for all directories/files. Then I tried to take ownership and I had no success, so I had the idea of disabling inheritance erasing all permissions and, accidentally it ended up with empty permissions, now I can't do anything with those files/directories. How to reset the permissions in a way that I can delete all the application's files/directories?

Comment: You get empty permissions because you lack rights that you had before. In order to fix this, go to a folder higher in the tree where you DO have permissions, and from there propogate permissions down to subdirectories. This can be done at the same place where you change the inheritance, except, its the 2nd checkbox.

Comment: I tried, the ones that are with empty permissions, gives me an access denied error and I can't propagate from the topmost folder to those ones. I tried executing with administrator rights, no success either!

Comment: Then do the same but with set owner ship. I haven't been locked out from a folder that I could not restore.

Comment: I tried too, at the topmost folder I changed it's ownership, marked the option to propagate and, during ownership change process, windows gave me access denied error to take ownership too on all subfolders, only the folder that I executed the ownership process changed ownership. I've never been in this situation before, it's very strange, because I'm locked in all conventional ways I tried.

Comment: NOTHING will propagate when inheritance is deactivated. You must reactivate inheritance, OR change the advanced access permissions for EVERY file and EVERY directory in that part of the directory tree.

Comment: I'll try a live Linux boot CD and use ntfs-3g to delete it. The NTFS driver is more permissive in Linux, it doesn't check permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following way from an elevated Command Prompt started by a user with Administrative permissions:

**takeown /f "C:\folder\folder-to-delete" /a**

**icacls "C:\folder\folder-to-delete" /inheritance:e**

This will exercise the Administrative user's Take ownership of files user right to grant the Administrators group ownership of the object. The second command adds all of the permissions to the folder it should inherit from its parent object.

Versus problems like being open in another process, or malicious code on the system.

Comment: This could work, if he has permissions to become owner. May be required to push ownership from a higher level though, and if that's the case, this will fail.

Comment: takeown /f "C:\folder\folder-to-delete" /a /r, all subfolders gives access denied error and I can't get ownership

icacls "C:\folder\folder-to-delete" /inheritance:e it doesn't gives me back the permissions inherited from the topmost folders.

Trying to get the owner of the subfolders, it shows unable to display current owner

Comment: @LeandroJacques As an Administrator you have the ability to add yourself to the ACL.

Comment: @Ramhound I know this, but, don't know why, even opening CMD as admin, I'm having access denied for all operations I try.

Answer (score -1):

[Open cmd.exe **as administrator**](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/how-to-open-a-windows-10-elevated-command-prompt/).

cd to the directory that contains the one you want to delete.

Then do:
rmdir "dirname" /S /Q

Make sure you type in the actual name of the directory, and not "dirname".

Check out [this link](http://www.ntfs.com/ntfs-permissions.htm) to gain a better understanding of how NTFS permissions work.

Comment: This won't work given that the user doesn't have permissions.

Comment: I lack all permissions to do this, as described in my question

Comment: @LPChip An admin account without permissions? No such thing!